# Multi-split in Python

Tags: python, string, split

How would I split a string by two opposing values? For example `(` and `)` are the "deliminators" and I have the following string:

```
Wouldn't it be (most) beneficial to have (at least) some idea?
```

I need the following output (as an array)

```
["Wouldn't it be ", "most", " beneficial to have ", "at least", " some idea?"]
```

Comment: In Python they are more commonly known as "lists," not arrays. There are also "dicts," equivalent to PHP's associative arrays.

Comment: @quantum: Thanks. I know the "proper" term, but it's the same as saying `show tables` in Mongo. Mongo has no tables, yet cheerfully accepts it and shows you all collections.

Comment: @Josh K: No, calling lists arrays is just wrong. It's like calling a bicycle a car because both have wheels.

Comment: @THC: They are arrays in every other language. Give me a break!

Comment: @Josh K: No, arrays and lists are not the same thing in *any* language.

Comment: @Josh K: My (deleted) solution was a little intensive as you commented. I misunderstood the problem. i thought that you wanted to split on the words 'most' and 'at least' and was giving you some idea of how to do it with a generator.

Comment: @Josh K: type `from array import array` and `array == list`. Results might be somewhat surprising...

Comment: @cji: I'm not arguing that Python calls them `lists`. I'm saying from a Java / PHP background, you will have to excuse me when I slip and say `array` when the *technically correct term* is `list`.

Comment: @Josh Java has lists too. Arrays and lists are **completely** different data structures.

Comment: There's a difference between an array data type (the interface) and an array memory structure (how it is implemented). If you consider the list of python, you'll notice that it can be seen as both an array (slicing/indexing) and a list (.append/.extend). This is why in for example java it is called an arraylist.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[re.split](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html)()

```
s = "Wouldn't it be (most) beneficial to have (at least) some idea?"
l = re.split('[()]', s);
```

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, sounds like it would make more sense to first split by space and then trim the brackets.

```
out = []
for element in "Wouldn't it be (most) beneficial to have (at least) some idea?".split():
  out.append(element.strip('()'))
```

Hm... re-reading the question, you wanted to preserve some of the spaces, so maybe not :) but keeping it here still.

Comment: I would *prefer* to keep spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the split of a regular expression:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'[()]')
pattern.split("Wouldn't it be (most) beneficial to have (at least) some idea?")
["Wouldn't it be ", 'most', ' beneficial to have ', 'at least', ' some idea?']
```

Comment: You don't need to escape the `()` inside a character class.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression, matching both `()` characters:

```
import re
re.split('[()]', string)
```